# Regression: Significance of unknown predictor

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, missing-data

**Problem**

I have a linear regression problem of the form `z ~ x + y + b` where `z`, `y` and `x` are continuous variables and `b` is categorical with two levels `A` and `B`. The information if a sample is `b=A` or `b=B` got lost for all samples. However I've always got **pairs of data** from which I know that one of them is `A`, the other one `B` (in total 27 pairs). I just don't know which is which.

I want to determine if `b` is a significant factor to the model and compare the strength of its effect to `x` and `y`

**Idea**

So far I've been thinking about a Monte Carlo simulation randomly assigning the classes and then doing the regression analysis and evaluating the p-value and the effect strength. I will end up with a distribution of these variables. Will their median then be the *most probable* p-value and effect strength? I'm not sure about this. Are there better strategies?

Comment: One note is that this regression would usually be written: $Y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3$ rather than as you have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you are out of luck. In each pair, the observation with the higher `z` could have `b=A` and the one with the lower `z` have `b=B`, and `b` would have a significant impact. Or the other way around, and you would again have a significant impact of `b` - but with the opposite sign! Or, thirdly, `z` and `b` could have zero relationship, and within each pair, the values of `b` could simply be random permutations of `A` and `B`. All three possibilities are completely consistent with your setup.

Unless, that is, `b` is related in some way to `x` and `y`. But to assess that, you would again need *labeled* samples for `b`. And if you already *know* that such a relationship exists, then you don't need your missing value dataset.

Comment: I just realise that I didn't point out that each pair has same `x` and `y`, they _only_ differ in `b`. It also doesn't matter in which direction the effect of `b` points, only if it's there and how strong it is. Does this change things?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Note how I didn't refer to `x` and `y` in my first paragraph. That's not because I forgot, that's because they are irrelevant (except for a potential relationship between them and `b`, per my second paragraph). Any arrangement is *a priori* equally likely, unless you have grounds to assume one is more likely than another. In short: if you don't know anything, then you can't draw any conclusions.